# Recursive parent child query with Sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model for organization, which contains two attributes

- org_id
- parent_org_id  (contains org_id of parent organization)

An organization may be nested down to sub-organizations at many levels.

How can I make a recursive parent-child query with sequelize in order to get the queried org and all child orgs?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find an answer to this in Sequelize.js, so I did a raw recursive SQL query (CTE) in Sequelize.js to get the data as I wanted.